# (Modified Descriptive) Shell scripting to How to display the specific contents of the search string?

Tags: unix

Here is my query :

```
/path/newdir/newtext.csv
```

newtext.csv looks like below :

### Record 1

line 1
line 2
Sample Number: 123456789 (line no. 3)
|
|
|
|
|
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z (line no. 21)
|
|
|
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z (line no. 30)

### Record 2

line 1
line 2
Sample Number: 363214563 (line no. 3)
|
|
|
|
|
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z (line no. 21)
|
|
|
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z (line no. 30)

### Record 3

line 1
line 2
Sample Number: 987654321 (line no. 3)
|
|
|
|
|
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z (line no. 21)
|
|
|
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z (line no. 30)

Assume there are such 100 records in a newtext.csv
So, now i need the parameters of the entered i/p string, which is something below

Example Input Search String :

```
123456789
```

Example Output :

```
Sample Number: 123456789
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z
```

This is what exactly i need. Can you please help me ?

Comment: tried with the grep command. Bt i could retrieve only one parameter, which i have given say something: 
grep 123456789 newfile.csv

Comment: @ Jaguar : Can u help me plzz ?

Comment: please clarify your input data, is it all on one line as klashxx assumes, or a multi-line record per Kev's reply? To get data to properly display, use the 'code' format tool '{}' at the top of the edit box. Select the text that you want to appear as-is, (without paragraph wrapping, etc), and click the '{}'. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`Perl` should be more *suitable* for this task.

```
    $ cat newtext.csv 
    line 1 line 2 Sample Number: 123456789 (line no. 3) | | | | | Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z (line no. 21) | | | Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z (line no. 30)
    line 1 line 2 Sample Number: 363214563 (line no. 3) | | | | | Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z (line no. 21) | | | Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z (line no. 30)
    line 1 line 2 Sample Number: 987654321 (line no. 3) | | | | | Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z (line no. 21) | | | Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z (line no. 30)
```

You can get the expected result using a *one-liner*, no matter the number of fields, just compose the regular expression.

```
# perl -lane '/(Sample Number:\s*\d+).*(Time In:\s*\S+).*(Time Out:\s*\S+)/;print $1."\n".$2."\n".$3' newtext.csv
Sample Number: 123456789
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z
Sample Number: 363214563
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z
Sample Number: 987654321
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z
```